# Use Array or QueryList to hold a list of Components in a Service?

Tags: angular, angular-services

I created a PopupService as follows:

```
export class PopupService {

  popups: PopupComponent[] = [];

  open(popup: PopupComponent) {
    this.popups.forEach(popup => popup.active = false);
    popup.active = true;
  }

  close(popup: PopupComponent) {
    popup.active = false;
  }  

}
```

Should popups should be a QueryList instead of an Array?

```
popups: QueryList<PopupComponent>;
```

The PopupComponent is the following:

```
export class PopupComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() active: boolean = false;

  constructor(public popupService: PopupService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.popupService.popups.push(this);
  }

  close() {
    this.popupService.close(this);
  }

  toggle() {
    if (this.active)
      this.popupService.close(this);
    else
      this.popupService.open(this);
  }

}
```

Comment: what makes you think that you should use `QueryList<T>`?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo I have seen QueryList<T> being used to hold child components along with ViewChildren. And that can also being used with NgFor. But in the case of my PopupService I am not using neither. So not sure what other advantages would have to use a QueryList vs Array.

Comment: Most likely in those cases the `QueryList<T>` instance was managed by angular itself. IMO the API of that class was not thought for such an use case as yours. I argument more about this in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short:** for your use case, a simple array should be enough

**Long:** you shouldn't use `QueryList<T>` in your use case for 2 reasons documented [in the docs](https://angular.io/api/core/QueryList):

1. Its an abstraction of an immutable list, so you cant do stuff like `this.popupService.popups.push(this);`. You could ofc overcome this by adapting the api of your service.
2. Its supposed to store references provided by `ViewChildren` and
   `ContentChildren`, which you arent using. So basically, angular should be in charge of managing instances of it, not you. This is the main reason behind my answer.